# Spring Security AccessDeniedException caught by @ExceptionHandler

Tags: spring-security

I have following spring-security.xml

```
<security:global-method-security proxy-target-class="true" secured-annotations="enabled" />
<security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="customLoginEndpoint" >
    <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
</security:http>

<bean id="authenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
    p:authenticationManager-ref="customAuthenticationManager"/>
```

And below is customLoginEndpoint

```
@Component("customLoginEndpoint")
public class CustomLoginEndpoint extends LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint
{
    public AcapLoginEndpoint()
    {
        super("/auth/login");
    }

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authenticationException) 
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendRedirect("/auth/login");
    }   
}
```

My controller clas has an @ExceptionHandler(Throwable ex) and few methods having @Secured annotation

The problem is that the @ExceptionHandler method catches all org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException caused by @Secured annotations and thus the request never comes to CustomLoginEndpoint.commence and gets rejected.

If I remove @ExceptionHandler then all works well.

How do I get this working so that commence is called and avoid @ExceptionHandler catching AccessDeniedException that are due to @Secured annotation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to add another @ExceptionHandler for AccessDeniedException and then simply rethrow the exception in the handle method. This would allow AccessDeniedException to propagate up so that Spring Security can handle the error.

Comment: Great, that worked? But is there any side effect of this solution?

Comment: The only downside I can think of is a possible **very small** overhead of catching and rethrowing the Exception.

Comment: As a side-effect you will get a log messsage with level ERROR for the "failed" handler method (the one re-throwing the AccessDeniedException) which you would not get without the "catch-the-world" @ExceptionHandler

Comment: @Holgzn had exactly same problem in Spring Boot, Security OAuth2 Resource server, worked perfectly and no additional log message.