# Propagate AccessDeniedException to Spring Security 3.2

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using global method security in Spring Security 3.2 and Spring 4.1.7 (Boot 1.2.5).  Spring's global method security interceptors throw an `AccessDeniedException`.  However, I have an exception handler annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` with an `ExceptionHandler` method that catches `Exception`, so the AccessDeniedException does not propagate up to the Spring Security `ExceptionResolvingFilter`; hence, it is not handled by Spring Security.

I tried following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533409/spring-security-accessdeniedexception-caught-by-exceptionhandler) and created another `ExceptionHandler` method that specifically handles `AccessDeniedException` and simply rethrows it.  But the exception again never makes it up to Spring Security; it is swallowed by Spring's `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` at line 366:

```
// ============ SPRING'S EXCEPTIONHANDLEREXCEPTIONRESOLVER CODE ==========
try {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Invoking @ExceptionHandler method: " + exceptionHandlerMethod);
    }
    exceptionHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(webRequest, mavContainer, exception);
}
catch (Exception invocationEx) {
    if (logger.isErrorEnabled()) {
        logger.error("Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: " + exceptionHandlerMethod, invocationEx);
    }
    return null;
}
```

How can I get the `AccessDeniedException` to propagate to Spring Security? Must I create a custom `ExceptionResolver` and subclass and rewrite that one method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, what I had to do was add a method to the `@ControllerAdvice` class:

```
@ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
public ResponseEntity<WebServiceResponse> handleAccessDeniedException(AccessDeniedException ex)
{
    WebServiceResponse response = new WebServiceResponseWithError(status: 'failure', message: ex.message, errorCode: 1007)
    return new ResponseEntity(response, HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
}
```

`WebServiceResponse` is a class I wrote for structuring the response.

This works, although I'm mimicing Spring's exception handling...

Answer (score 0):

your code swallowed the exception

```
catch (Exception invocationEx) {
    if (logger.isErrorEnabled()) {
        logger.error("Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: " + exceptionHandlerMethod, invocationEx);
    }
    return null; // here is the culprit
}
```

it would be good to just logged it or re-throw it

```
catch (Exception invocationEx) {
    if (logger.isErrorEnabled()) {
        logger.error("Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: " + exceptionHandlerMethod, invocationEx);
    }
    throw invocationEx;
}
```

Comment: That's the problem: it's not my code, it's Spring's.  `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver`, line 366.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by just setting the error in response object by adding following code in `@ControllerAdvice` class.

```
  @ExceptionHandler (value = {AccessDeniedException.class})
  public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
      AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException {
    response.sendError(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, accessDeniedException.getMessage());
  }
```